# How to translate "動いた拍子に" this?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

For context this is the whole sentence.
"動いた拍子に,立て掛けて置いた刀が倒れかけ慌てて押さえた.".

"立て掛けて置いた刀が倒れかけ慌てて押さえた"
I know that the gist of this part is that a sword was placed against something and fell over.
But I need some help with the meaning of "動いた拍子に" this part.  I know from this  "動" kanjj that it's talking about movement but I am unsure of how to translate the rest of it.

Comment: You've been asked for more context before; please don't ignore these requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

動いた拍子に means "at the moment (something) moved." You don't show the previous sentences so the subject of 動いた is unclear.

My guess is the protagonist of the sentence stood up, started walking or whatever then the sword placed against something, perhaps a wall, fell over and the person quickly caught it.

Comment: There is no previous sentence, but for more context this is happening on a moving train.

Comment: Then the subject could be the train. As a matter of fact, things held against a wall of a train can fall down when it moves.